# e2e test failing - getRepository is null

Tags: jestjs, typeorm, nest

When I run the e2e test(as integration tests) I get a getRepository null error. I import the entire app module in my test spec file(below),the error occurs,  which says something like this:

```
[Nest] 47867  - 08/22/2022, 8:07:35 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'getRepository' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRepository' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRepository' of null
    at new usersService (/mypath/src/users/users.service.ts:35:42)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:330:19)
    at callback (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:48:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:52:9)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:74:9)
    at Injector.resolveComponentHost (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:192:13)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.loadCtorMetadata (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:358:23)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/mypath/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:89:26)
 FAIL  test/user.service.int-spec.ts (10.525 s)
  GET /users 
    ✓ (GET) / (102 ms)
    ✕ (GET) /users (62 ms)

  ● GET /users  › (GET) /users

    expected 200 "OK", got 500 "Internal Server Error"

      26 |
      27 |   it('(GET) /users', () => {
    > 28 |     return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/users').expect(200);
         |                                                           ^
      29 |   });
      30 | });
      31 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/user.service.int-spec.ts:28:59)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:306:17
      at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
```

The folder structure is this:

```
parent_folder
| package.json
| package-lock.json
| ---src
|    \-User
|       \-user.module.ts
|       \-user.service.ts
|       \-user.controller.ts
|...
| ---tests
|    \-jest-int.json
|    \-user.int-spec.ts  


The jest config file contains this:
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": "../",  // <<<--- I use absolute path path, so rootDir is "../"
  "roots": ["<rootDir>"],
  "modulePaths": ["<rootDir>"],
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".int-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

The module contains this only:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersController } from './Users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './Users.service';

@Module({
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

The service contains:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private userRepository: Repository<User>;
  private fileRepository: Repository<file>;
  private filedworthRepository: Repository<filedworth>;
  private filedValueRepository: Repository<filedValue>;
  private fileStrategyRepository: Repository<fileStrategy>;
  private valueRepository: Repository<Value>;
  private defaultData = {
    created_date: new Date(),
    updated_date: new Date(),
    created_by: 'user',
    updated_by: 'user',
  };

  constructor(@Inject(CONNECTION) private connection: DataSource) {
    this.userRepository = connection.getRepository(user);
    this.fileRepository = connection.getRepository(file);
    this.filedworthRepository =
      connection.getRepository(filedworth);
    this.filedValueRepository =
      connection.getRepository(filedValue);
    this.fileStrategyRepository =
      connection.getRepository(fileStrategy);
    this.ValueRepository = connection.getRepository(Value);
  }
  ...//other methods
}
```

The controller is:

```
@Controller('users')
export class usersController {
  constructor(private usersService: usersService) {}

  @Get()
  getusers(
    @Query()
    query: GetUsersFilterDto,
  ) {
    return this.usersService.getusers(query);
  }
  ...//others
}
```

and the test file itself contains the following:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';

describe('GET /users ', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('(GET) /', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/').expect(200);
  });

  it('(GET) /users', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/users').expect(200);
  });
});
```

I run the test using:

```
npm run test:int // "test:int": "jest -i --no-cache  --detectOpenHandles --config ./test/jest-int.json"
```

Is there something I'm missing? Hopefully these are enough details to convey my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Georgi has mentioned was true, I hadn't provided the values of the dependency `CONNECTION` that was being injected. But, the syntax mentioned there didn't work, this did:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const connection = await DataSource(myDB_Config);//hosturl, port etc.
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
      .overrideProvider(CONNECTION)
      .useValue(connection)
      .compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

    await app.init();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add CONNECTION as a provider to your test app: TestingModule =

```
await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: CONNECTION, getRepository: jest.fn() },
  ],
}).compile();
```

Comment: hey, thanks for replying, really appreciate it. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue, I'm wondering if importing AppModule would have already done the import for connection for respective module...

Comment: Hey, Did you also mock the methods that you are calling in the service like getRepository ? Also in "provide" you need to provide an instance of the connection class. AFAIK the AppModule won't import the connection service by itself since in the jest file you are generating a new instance without passing a value for that class.

Comment: but, we're connecting to an actual database, mocking the getRepository would be.... difficult?